# How to instanciate an object regularly on the surface of an other object

Tags: modeling, geometry, instances, geometry-nodes

I'm in the process of modelling a building similar to reference picture below. I'm struggling with the part I highlighted in red. I can easily model one of these objects, but I'm looking for a way to repeat them regularly with consistent spacing on different surfaces of my mesh. As you can see, the orientations of the different surfaces are different.

I tried different options :

- Particules/Geometry nodes : I can't find a way to make it not random and have consistent spacing. Having the orientation follow the base geometry also seem challenging but my experience with geometry nodes is very limited.
- Using instances on faces : I managed to get a somewhat decent result by copying only one strip of my building mesh, inserting loopcuts at each spot where I want to instanciate the child object and configuring an instancer on faces. It's tedious because I need to adjust the number of cuts on each face to have an even spacing and making the corners look good take a lot of fiddling.

Does someone has a smarter idea ? Thank you.

[image: Reference picture]

Comment: Thank you. I experimented with the idea, I used the array + curve modifier technique on a small plane, then I used face instance to instantiate my geometry. If I use the technique directly on my geometry, it deforms a lot in the corners. Here is the result of my quick test : https://imgur.com/a/0qR2ivU

Comment: At the risk of stating the bleeding obvious - why would you not just use an array modifier?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with Geometry nodes like this:

[image]

In this "easy" case i took a line to distribute the "art"/suzanne on the points.

You can do the same with a curve. Just add a curve with the points you need. Convert it to mesh -> use this as "object info" and connect it to point instance instead of the "line primitive".

Video tutorial: https://youtu.be/JDjq1YQpWgs

Comment: Thank you. It's useful already, but I'm not sure how I can use this in connection with my parent geometry to guide the instancing.

Comment: maybe watch the video tutorial: there is also an explanation how to use it with curves